# Некорректно работает задний план в QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qscrollarea

Идея вот в чём: список лэйблов с текстом, с прозрачным фоном, чтобы на заднем плане была видна установленная картинка.

Использую для этого `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground`, но при прокрутке вниз `label` с изображением, который на заднем плане укатывается вместе с текстом. 
И ещё одно - как убрать границы окна?

**Upd**: проблему с фоном решил строкой `self.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")`, но осталась небольшая тонка рамка вокруг окна, которую нужно убрать(видно на скрине ниже).

[image: деловой кот]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QAction, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea
from threading import Thread



class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('win')
        self.show()
        self.dd = DragNDropWindow()
        self.dd.show()


class DragNDropWindow(QWidget, Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        background = QLabel(self)
        bpixmap = QPixmap('mindsbackground.png')
        background.setPixmap(bpixmap)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        background.show()

        with open('minds.txt') as mindList:
            mindList = mindList.read()
        minds = mindList.split(sep='@@\n@@')

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.setSpacing(15)

        for i in minds:
            label = QLabel(self)
            label.setText(i)
            label.setFixedWidth(420)
            label.setStyleSheet('''
                            font: 10pt "Jack Brusher(RUS BY LYAJKA)";
                            background-color: #778899;
                            border-radius: 5px;
                            color: #FFFFE0;
                            padding: 15;
                                    ''')
            label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
            action = QAction("Скрыть текст", self)
            action.triggered.connect(label.hide)
            label.addAction(action)
            vbox.addWidget(label)

        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollarea.resize(background.width(), background.height())
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        area = QWidget()
        area.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        area.setLayout(vbox)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(area)
        self.scrollarea.setStyleSheet("""
        QScrollBar:vertical {              
            border: none;
            background:white;
            width:7px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
    """)

        self.resize(background.width(), background.height())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А не проще бэкграунд в stylesheet запихать и сразу приклеить куда надо?

Comment: Я же у него ещё размеры беру.

Comment: а если написать в stylesheet `border:none;`?

Comment: о, отлично сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, я действительно не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать, 
но я добавил некоторые изменения, которые отметил по тексту.

Теперь окно (назовем его `DragNDropWindow`) можно перетаскивать. 
Добавил контекстного меню "Показать текст". 
По закрытию основного окна закрывается и окно `DragNDropWindow` ...

Пробуйте, может это добавит вам каких-либо идей.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QAction, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea
from threading import Thread


class DragNDropWindow(QWidget): #, Thread):                      # ?
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                             # + parent
        super(DragNDropWindow, self).__init__(parent)            # + parent

        self.setStyleSheet('border: none;')                      # +++

        # +++               vvvvvvvvv
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)     # попробуйте закомментировать !!!     

        self.background = QLabel(self)                           # + self.
        bpixmap = QPixmap('lena-removebg-preview.png')           # 'mindsbackground.png'
        self.background.setPixmap(bpixmap)
        self.background.show()

        with open('test.txt') as mindList:                       # 'minds.txt'
            mindList = mindList.read()
        minds = mindList.split(sep='@@\n@@')

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.setSpacing(15)

        for i in minds:
            label = QLabel(self)
            label.setText(i)
            label.setFixedWidth(420)
            label.setStyleSheet('''
                font: 10pt "Jack Brusher(RUS BY LYAJKA)";
                background-color: #778899;
                border-radius: 5px;
                color: #FFFFE0;
                padding: 15;
            ''')
            label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
            action = QAction("Скрыть текст", self)
            action.triggered.connect(label.hide)
            label.addAction(action)
            vbox.addWidget(label)

        # + добавил перенос слов на label                                  # +++
        label.setWordWrap(True)                                            
        # +  добавил контекстного меню "Показать текст"                    # +++
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
        action2 = QAction("Показать текст", self)
        action2.triggered.connect(label.show)
        self.addAction(action2)

        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollarea.resize(self.background.width(), self.background.height())
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        area = QWidget()
        area.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)               
        area.setLayout(vbox)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(area)

        self.scrollarea.setStyleSheet("""
            QScrollBar:vertical {              
                border: none;
                background: white;
                width: 7px;
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }
        """)

        self.resize(self.background.width(), self.background.height())

# +++ VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
#       это позволяеи перетаскивать данное окно
        self._old_pos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self._old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self._old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('MyWin')
#        self.show()
        self.dd = DragNDropWindow(self)             # + self 
        self.dd.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавил в вопрос скриншот проблемы с рамкой. Но огромное спасибо за Ваш код, подметил много полезных фишек, плюсанул.